# My max value wont display, but i cant see or figure out why

Tags: java, arrays, function, max

I am trying to find the maximum value a user has entered from a 1D array, but the function i have set up wont display a value. I usually use visual basic and have done limited java, so I'm new.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int i = 0;
        int data[];
        data = new int[5];
        
        for (i = 0; i <5; i ++) {
        
        System.out.println("Please enter your " + (i + 1)+ " number");
        data[i] = scan.nextInt();

    }
        
        System.out.println(data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3] + data[4]);
    
    int max = findMax(data);
    System.out.println(max);
```

```
public static int findMax(int data[]){
        
        int max = data[0];
        int element = 1;
        
        while (element != 5); {
            
            if (data[element] > max) {
                max = data[element];
            }
        
        }
        
        
        System.out.println(max);
        return max;
        
        }
```

I would be expecting a max value, however nothing is displayed at all, but the program hasnt terminated.

Comment: `while (element != 5); {` will run forever as `element` is never changed ... which begs the question of what happens if `element` is never `5`

Comment: I often forget stupid things like not incremementing on a conditional loop, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`while (element != 5);` causes an infinite loop. First, remove the `;` after it as that makes the body of the loop an empty statement. Next, note that `element` is never changed after being initialized to `1`, so the loop condition `element != 5` is always true.

If you wanted to use `element` as the index for iterating over the array, you should increment it at the end of the loop block in order to process the next element.

```js
while (element != 5) {
    if (data[element] > max) {
        max = data[element];
    }
    ++element;
}
```

Note that it would be better to compare with `data.length` rather than hardcoding the value `5`.

Or, even better, use an enhanced for loop to avoid handling the indexes yourself when you don't need them:

```java
for (int num : data) max = Math.max(max, num);
```

An alternative solution with streams:

```java
return Arrays.stream(data).max().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Comment: thanks, i am prone to making mistakes like this, but this has been very helpful thank you.